# javascript: scrollTo по клику не работает после slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

1. Элемент `id=before` по клику исчезает, но открывает `id=hiddencontent` под ним.
2. В самом `hiddencontent` есть элемент `id=after`, по клику закрывающий `hiddencontent` и открывающий обратно `id=before`, закрытый пунктом 1.

Для второго действия хочу добавить также прокрутку наверх, к элементу `id=sometopid`, а то после исчезновения `hiddencontent` оказываемся в случайной точке по вертикали страницы, что неправильно.

Подключён  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

```
 $("#before").click(function () {
     $("#hiddencontent").stop().slideToggle();
     $("#beforecontainer").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });

 $("#after").click(function () {
     $("#hiddencontent").stop().slideToggle();
     $("#beforecontainer").stop().slideToggle();
     $.scrollTo($('#sometopid'), 1000);

     return false;
 });
```

Куда копать?  Всё хорошо, кроме `scrollTo`

Comment: что-то я в документации по jquery не нашел такого метода.. может его просто нет? ошибки какие в консоли?

Comment: Может быть все-таки `scrollTop` а не `scrollTo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scrollTo это метод window а не jQuery. Вот так реализовывайте.

```
 $("#before").click(function () {
     $("#hiddencontent").stop().slideToggle();
     $("#beforecontainer").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });

 $("#after").click(function () {
     $("#hiddencontent").stop().slideToggle();
     $("#beforecontainer").stop().slideToggle();
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#sometopid").offset().top
     }, 1000);

     return false;
 });
```